# Transcendence basis and spanning.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

From Basic Abstract Algebra (Robert Ash):

> ...the element $t \in E$ *depends algebraically on $T$* over $F$ if $t$ is algebraic over $F(T)$, the field generated by $T$ over $F$...We say that *$T$ spans E algebraically over $F$* if each $t$ in $E$ depends algebraically on $T$ over $F$, that is $E$ is an algebraic extension of $F(T)$.

I was trying to show that if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F(x)$ and if x is algebraic over $F(y_1, y_2)$ (and if $\alpha$ depends algebraically on $x$ over F), then $\alpha$ must be algebraic over $F(y_1, y_2)$, but I was a bit confused.

Let's suppose that (I'm just making these up) $\alpha x + a = 0$ for $a \in F$ and $y_1x + y_2x^2 = 0$. Now I cannot see how it is possible for $\alpha$ to be algebraic over $F(y_1, y_2)$, because we know that $x$ is not included in $F(y_1, y_2)$. Then how can $\alpha$ be algebraic over it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $\sqrt2$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q[\sqrt3]$, despite not being included there.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No I meant how is $\alpha$ algebraic over $F(y_1, y_2)$ when it is algebraically dependent on $x$ and $x \not\in F(y_1 ,y_2)$. I didn't mean how is $x$ algebraic over $F(y_1, y_2)$ when it is not included in it. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough...

Comment: Asaf's comment still holds: $\sqrt{2}$ is algebraically dependent on $5\sqrt{2}$, which is not included in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$.

Comment: @Billy Thanks a lot. I guess I didn't understand his comment. But I still don't understand how/why that's true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see it: a field extension $F\subseteq F(x)$ is algebraic iff $F(x)$ has finite dimension as a vector field over $F$.

In your case, the dimension of $F(x,y_1,y_2)$ over $F(y_1,y_2)$ is finite, and dimension of $F(x,\alpha)$ over $F(x)$ is finite. Use those two to show that the dimension of $F(x,\alpha,y_1,y_2)$ over $F(y_1,y_2)$ is finite.

Edit: In hindsight, I think it's easier to use another equivalent condition, namely that $F\subseteq F(x)$ is algebraic iff $F[x]$ has finite dimension as a vector field over $F$, so we have to show that $F(y_1,y_2)[x,\alpha]$ has finite dimension over $F(y_1,y_2)$.